# glBindAttribLocation whats next?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm struggling to find OpenGL/GLSL examples that don't require glew or glut or what have you.

I'm trying to work with only using glfw3 (if possible I would like to use no other libraries) and I'm struggling to understand what to do once I use glBindAttribLocation? I've written code to pass an image as a texture into shaders, but I can't figure how to pass vertices.

I have a vertex shader and fragment shader I want to make a triangle and then color it red, I can create the shader programs and object program and link everything, but how do I pass things to the shaders.

```
// vert
in vec3 vPosition;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vPosition,1.0);
}


// Frag
out vec4 color;
void main()
{
    color = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

I don't understand what I need to do after I call glBindAttribLocation

```
glBindAttribLocation(p,0,"vPosition");
glUseProgram(p);
```

now how do I pass the vertices of a triangle into the shader?

more code, I'm calling my own library to read in the files so the textread won't work if anyone tries to run it

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "src/textfile.h"

GLuint v,f,p;


void printLog(GLuint obj)
{
    int infologLength = 0;
    int maxLength;

    if(glIsShader(obj))
        glGetShaderiv(obj,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&maxLength);
    else
        glGetProgramiv(obj,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&maxLength);

    char infoLog[maxLength];

    if (glIsShader(obj))
        glGetShaderInfoLog(obj, maxLength, &infologLength, infoLog);
    else
        glGetProgramInfoLog(obj, maxLength, &infologLength, infoLog);

    if (infologLength > 0)
        printf("%s\n",infoLog);
}

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fputs(description, stderr);
}

static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

void setShaders() {

    char *vs = NULL,*fs = NULL;

    v = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    f = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    vs = textFileRead("toon.vert");
    fs = textFileRead("toon.frag");

    const char * ff = fs;
    const char * vv = vs;

    glShaderSource(v, 1, &vv,NULL);
    glShaderSource(f, 1, &ff,NULL);

    free(vs);free(fs);

    glCompileShader(v);
    glCompileShader(f);

    p = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(p,f);
    glAttachShader(p,v);

    glLinkProgram(p);
    //glUseProgram(p);
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);

    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        int height, width;
        float ratio;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float) height;
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        setShaders();


        glBindAttribLocation(p,0,"vPosition");
        glUseProgram(p);
        /* Now What */


        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Note that calls to `glBindAttribLocation` only take effect after you link the shader program, so you need to move the call to your `setShaders` function.

Comment: That is how I have it set up the setShaders(); links the shaders then I call glBindAttribLocation, then I use the program, But I don't understand how to use the shader after it tell it to use program. How do I pass in vertices to the vertex shader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you "pass vertices into the shaders" by making a draw call, most typically glDrawArrays().

when glDrawArrays() hits, the currently bound vertex array gets sent off to GPU-land.  the vertices will be processed by the currently bound program (which you seem to have figured out) and each vertex attribute will flow into the vertex shader variables based on whether or not the shader variable's attribute index matches the vertex attribute's glVertexAttribPointer() "index" parameter (which you seem on the way to figuring out).

so, look into glVertexAttribPointer() to describe your array of vertices, glEnableAttributeArray() to enable your array of vertices to be sent on the next draw call, and then glDrawArrays() to kick off the party.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call glBindAttribLocation, use [glGetAttribLocation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glGetAttribLocation.xml) instead.

1 Define attribute variable in your cpp file

```
GLint vPosition
```

2 Bind shader variables

```
const char* attribute_name = "vPosition"; 
attribute_coord2d = glGetAttribLocation(p, attribute_name);
```

3 in vertex shader file, define vPosition as attribute variable and use it.

```
attribute vec3 vPosition;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vPosition,1.0);
}
```

Comment: I know at that stuff already I choose to do  it in a different way. But what I'm stuck on is the use it part. Where do a provide the vertices? after I used glgetattribloction/glbindattriblocation then what?

Comment: Using glBindAttribLocation is useful for standardizing attribute locations so that you can use different meshes with the same shader, or vice versa.